# Slick JQuery UI plugins

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am developing a brand new site and like to have a very slick look and feel. I will be using the following in my website:

1. Tabs
2. Forms
3. Validation
4. Data grid

Can anyone help me find some really cool JQuery plugins for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Tabs

   - are handled by [jquery ui](http://jqueryui.com/home). It has excellent [theming](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/) support plus as added bonus you can host it from [google's CDN](http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/devguide.html#jqueryUI).
2. Forms

   - [Jquery form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/)
3. Validation

   - Jörn Zaefferer, a member of the jQuery team, has created jQuery plugin which makes simple [clientside form validation](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) trivial. Also has hosting on microsoft's CDN.
4. Data grid

   - I used [jqgrid](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid) in the past(Which is pretty popular). It had a github commit 10 hours ago so it is also maintained pretty good.

Comment: I thought JQGrid was not free for commercial purposes. At this time, I am looking for something I can use without restrictions for free for commercial websites.

Comment: Ok, this is confusing. This page http://www.trirand.net/licensing.aspx asks me to pay

Comment: Hehe Dave S you are right about that. I guess that if you want support, but it does not say it clearly on that page!

Answer (score 3):

So, I suppose you are able to style them to suit desing of site of yours.

**1.Tabs**
[jQuery UI Tabs](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tabs)

**2. Forms**
Do you mean something for form skinning? Here you go then. *Uniform* is the best I have ever used. It also contains 3 themes, and it is easy to create your own ;-)
[Uniform](http://pixelmatrixdesign.com/uniform/)
Autocomplete plugin has its magic as well, or maybe some date-pickers... :)
[autocomplete](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/), [jquery ui date-picker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/)
More here... http://jqueryui.com/demos/

**3. Form validation**
there is plenty of jQuery plugins over here. Here is example
[Form validation](http://www.willjessup.com/sandbox/jquery/form_validator/form_validate.html)

**4. Data grid**
Here is the link to a review article... It contains review of 10 jQuery data grid plugins. I think you will pick one ;-)
[Review article](http://php-team.blogspot.com/2009/05/10-jquery-datagrid-plugins.html)

Answer (score 1):

Agreed with Alfred on 1-3, but would suggest [Flexigrid](http://www.flexigrid.info/) for your data grid.